# Contador que muestre 0 cuando ya no tenga items Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un tema con un query que estoy haciendo y no comprendo como solucionarlo basicamente lo que deseo en este query es que me haga un conteo de cada uno de los items que esten con "STATUS == TRUE" hasta alli bien me cuenta unicamente los estados "TRUE" pero cuando llegue no haya ningun item de esa categoria simplemente me muestre un 0 este es mi codigo

```
$items = facturacion::select('clients_id', 'Status')
                ->selectRaw('count(clients_id) as c')
                ->groupBy('clients_id', 'Status')
                ->orderBy('clients_id', 'asc')                
                ->orderBy('Status', 'asc')
                ->get();
        
        foreach($items as $key => $value) {
            $b = $value['Status'] === 1;
            $c = $value['c'];
            if($b == true){
                 echo $c. ' t <br>';
            }else{
                echo '0 f<br>';
            }
        }
```

Sucede que cuando hay un item falso me muestra el true y el false a la vez solo quiero que me muestre un elemento... aqui dejo un ejemplo grafico. gracias de ante mano quien me pueda ayudar...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hasta lo que tengo entendido ```$b = $value['Status'] === 1;``` no es valido ya que si intentas verificar si Status es exactamente 1 lo correcto seria ```$b = ($value['Status'] === 1) ? 'true' : 'false';```

Comment: en raw as un selectRaw('count(CASE WHEN Status THEN 1 END) as c') o puedes hace cast to boolean $b = (bool) $value['Status'];

Comment: @Bryro hola que tal muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responderme...!! hice lo que me indicaste pero en principio hace lo mismo que ya tengo en mi propio codigo, intentare ser un poco mas especifico mi problema radica es que cuando hay 2 items de la misma categoria y uno esta activo y el otro esta inactivo me muestra 0 y me cuenta el que esta activo  yo quiero que me muestre 0 cuando no haya ningun item activo de esa categoria de resto no espero haberme explicado mejor disculpa las molestia

Comment: @ernestojimenez hola, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder intente con esto pero mi problema persiste y es que si hay 2 items de la misma categoria uno activo y otro inactivo me muestra 0 y 1 y yo deseo que solo me muestre el 0 cuando esten todo los items de esa misma categoria inactivos

Answer (score 0):

Actualización de este tema ya logre solucionar el problema para que me de 0 cuando todo los items esten en false y no duplique tanto falso como verdadero gracias a las 2 personas que me intentaron ayudar  aca dejare el codigo por si otra persona tiene el mismo problema...

```
$items = facturacion::select('clients_id')
            ->selectRaw('count(CASE WHEN Status THEN 1 END) as c')
            ->groupBy('clients_id')
            ->orderBy('clients_id', 'asc')                
            ->get();

    $itemsA = [];
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
            $var = $value['c'];            
            $var;
            array_push($itemsA, $var);
        
    }
```